# Generate the same keys with Rfc2898DeriveBytes in c# and pbkdf2 in go

Tags: c#, go, pbkdf2

Why do `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` in C# and  `pbkdf2` in go lang generate different keys?

my **C#** code

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class Test
{
        private static byte[] passBytes = new byte[]
        {164,176,124,62,244,154,226,211,177,90,202,180,12,142,25,225};

        private static byte[] saltBytes = new byte[]
        {173,205,190,172,239,190,242,63,219,205,173,196,218,171,142,214};

        public static byte[] GetKey()
        {
            var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(passBytes, 0, 16), saltBytes).GetBytes(16);
            return key;
        }

    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(GetKey()));
    }
}
```

**output:** 77U85CphtSEwPP9a2T/jaQ==

---

golang code

```golang
package main

import (

    b64 "encoding/base64"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/pbkdf2"
    "crypto/sha1"

)

var (
    pass[]byte = []byte{164,176,124,62,244,154,226,211,177,90,202,180,12,142,25,225}
    salt[]byte = []byte{173,205,190,172,239,190,242,63,219,205,173,196,218,171,142,214}
)


func getKey() (key[]byte){
    key =  pbkdf2.Key(pass,salt,1000,16,sha1.New)
    return
}


func main() {
    print(b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(getKey()))
}
```

**output:** hnuuu+he4aF7vAzA8rfQtw==

Is there something different i must do?

Comment: Do they both use the same iteration count and SHA1? Also using `UTF8` on `passBytes` seem suspect because the `passBytes` may not be a valid UTF-8 string.

Comment: The Rfc2898DeriveBytes ctors that takes a string just immediately turn it into bytes via the UTF-8 encoding.  You can skip the creation of the string by just passing the bytes directly to a byte[]-based ctor.

Comment: @bartonjs whats wrong in the c# code? Is `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(passBytes, 0, 16)` not the right encoding supposed to be used on `passBytes` ?

Comment: @avut My point is that you have bytes which you turn into a string (via UTF8) that you pass to a constructor that turns the string into bytes (via UTF8). You'd save work by just using one of the constructors that took bytes directly.

Comment: @bartonjs Alright! I get it what you mean. But why is the output different shouldn't it be same? What is making output different. Isn't default encoding in C# is UTF-16? So Turning string into UTF-8 should give the same output? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using different variant (the constructor that takes UTF-8 `string`) when initializing C# instance. In addition, as already pointed by zaph, you need to use same iteration count for both C# and `golang` codes. The `golang` version takes `[]byte` arguments both for *password* and *salt*, and the C# counterpart is [`Rfc2898DeriveBytes Constructor (Byte[] password, Byte[] salt, Int32 iterations)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148161(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
byte[] passBytes = new byte[]
    {164,176,124,62,244,154,226,211,177,90,202,180,12,142,25,225};

byte[] saltBytes = new byte[]
    {173,205,190,172,239,190,242,63,219,205,173,196,218,171,142,214};

var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
var key = Convert.ToBase64String(pbkdf2.GetBytes(16));
```

The output of above code is the same with `golang` version.

Comment: Thanks for reply. And in case I need to replicate the C# code in golang??

Comment: @avut It depends on which *C# functionality* that you want to replicate. If *iterations* is not specified in the C# constructor, I think the default value will be 1000. However, there are C# constructors that use random salt (`Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String, Int32, Int32)` and `Rfc2898DeriveBytes(String, Int32, Int32)`), and in this case you can't replicate.